# Most efficient way to find speed limit for a given latitude and longitude

Tags: here-api

I am new to Here-API and have been struggling for a couple of days. I want to achieve something like [this](https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/link_speed_locator) but a bit cleaner. I do not want to plot the point on the map. All I want is to retrieve the speed limit. I have tried a couple of things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57406563/9813285), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56934430/9813285). A humble request to please add demo get requests and not just the procedure.

Note: I only have an API Key, I am not looking for android/ios code. Just a demo Get request should be fine. I do not have app-code, app-id as I have a freemium subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find out what you want to know is to watch what happens when you input coordinates and press the Load button.

1. Using the Chrome browser, log in and go to the page.
2. Select **Menu** > **More Tools** > **Developer Tools**.
3. Click **Network** at the top of the screen.
4. Type in street coordinates and press **Load**.

What you see on the right side are the queries and results. The one you're interested in begins with:
`https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?` [continues]

Look at the return value of that call to get your results. The other queries are for the graphical display, so you don't need those.

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helped. I have made some edits to the answer. Please verify if it's good or not.